# Entity Framework is calling SQL Server many times

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple Web MVC app using database first Entity Framework. I am retrieving information from a table. It is very slow.

I have two problems:

1. When I review the query with SQL Server Profiler, it shows the query as a `Select` query with a from clause that is another select query. I'm not sure why it is using another select instead of the table name. Could this be slowing down the query?
2. When I am retrieving the rows, it is calling the database for each row slowing down the process. It is using the key from the table and requerying the database for each row. Why is it recalling the database for each row? Didn't the first query return all the rows?

Below is my code and SQL Server Profiler results.

**Code:**

```
List<FanDetail> fans = db.FanDetails.ToList();

foreach (var item in fans)
{
   FanSummaryViewModel add = new FanSummaryViewModel()
   {
     Part_No = item.Part_No,
   }
}
```

SQL Server Profiler results for the query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Part_No] AS [Part_No]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [FanDetails].[Part_No] AS [Part_No]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[FanDetails] AS [FanDetails]) AS [Extent1]
```

SQL Profiler Results on the For Each:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Part_No] AS [Part_No]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [FanDetails].[Part_No] AS [Part_No]
    FROM [dbo].[FanDetails] AS [FanDetails]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Part_No] = = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='00405635'
```

Let me know if I need to provide more detail.

I'm new to EF and been working on this performance issue for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve all the query and projection in a single query:

```
List<FanSummaryViewModel> fans = db.FanDetails
                                  .Select(item => new FanSummaryViewModel 
                                               {
                                                  Part_No = item.Part_No
                                               })
                                  .ToList();
```

The Select statement before the ToList will help the parser create a properly scoped query and will only return the fields referred to and create a new object for each row when the list is enumerated, which is what the ToList statement achieves.

You should also check the query performance of the generated Sql against the database directly to see if the issue is with the database only, which you may be able to fix with an index.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the feedback and help.  It reduced my page load time from 15-20 seconds to under 3 seconds. With your direction,  it was very simple to implement.